# Streaming Windows Media Center to Samsung Smart TV

Tags: tv, windows-media-center, smart-tv

I was wondering if there was any way in which I could stream shows that I have recorded with windows media center to my samsung smart tv without having to connect and xbox to it, I am very new to using windows media center and it seems as though I need to use an extender which I'm not sure if thats the only way to share over the network with windows media center or if there is some other way that I am simply not finding.

Comment: I have been very dissatisfied with Samsung's "smart tv" and associated software.  I just hooked up an old laptop to the tv and have much better functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need a DLNA server which can transcode the WTV file format which is what Windows Media Center saves recordings as.

I'd first try the content sharing built into Windows Media Player.

http://www.pcworld.com/article/245888/how_to_stream_digital_media_from_your_windows_7_pc.html

If that doesn't work then try Serviio which is very good (and supports WTV amongst a whole range of formats) but, unfortunately, requires Java to be installed. The free version will suffice.

http://serviio.org/

Answer (score 0):

First option is samsung way: http://help.content.samsung.com/csweb/faq/searchFaq.do?category1_id=samsunglink-b05&serviceCd=allshareplay&r_faq_id=120201#F_120201
Still, you can try other dlna servers, including windows media center but the result depends on the codec used (tvmobili is considered better) - so an extender could be needed sometimes.